# Why does non-linearity come into picture only at a large intensity of optical fields?

Tags: optical-materials, non-linear-optics, photonics

I have read that for sufficiently large intensities of optical fields (of the order of $10^8$), we can actually observe a non-linear relationship between the polarization and the field, given as
$$\vec{P}=\epsilon(\chi^{(1)}\vec{E} + \chi^{(2)}\vec{E}^2 + \ldots)$$ So, in that case, we need to  show that the non-linearity ceases to exist when the intensity (say along the $z$ direction) is low owing to high amounts of absorption, as stated by the equation
$$I = I_0 e^{-\alpha z}$$ where $\alpha$ is the absorption coefficient and it's sufficiently large in order to bring down the intensity. I feel that we need to show that in such a situation, the higher order terms of optical susceptibility $\chi^{(2)}$ and so on cease to exist, but I'm not being able to do so. Can someone help me out in this?

Comment: Hint: The eectro-magnetic coupling is small, about 1/137. Nonlinear processes involve higher orders of this coupling constant.

Comment: Okay, but I don't seem to understand how to incorporate that in my calculations. Can you rather suggest some other way where I can express the second-order optical susceptibility in terms of the absorption coefficient, perhaps?

Comment: If you add a linear term to a mathematical expression, nonlinear terms will be relatively smaller.

Comment: Yeah, but I need to show that right? It's not straightforward here as the susceptibilities themselves are tensors, starting from rank 2 itself. So, I need to show that the rank 3 tensor starting from the second order optical susceptibility brings down the outer product of optical fields to negligible results.